# $sum string values with $cond in array MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to `$sum` some values that match the next condition.

My collection:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    items: [ 
    {
        name: 'item1',
        status: 'On'
    },
    {
        name: 'item2',
        status: 'On'
    },
    {
        name: 'item3',
        status: 'Off'
    }]
}
```

I need to `$sum` all `items` that have status 'On'

This is what i am trying:

```
     {
        $addFields: {
            itemsOn: { "$sum": { "$cond": [{ if: { $eq: ["$items.status", 'On'] } }, { then: 1 }, { else: 0 }] } },
        }
    }
```

But it is not working, any help? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$filter` to filter items on the base of condition, `$size` to get total count of returned elements from filter,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      itemOn: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$items",
            cond: { $eq: ["$$this.status", "On"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7rSzeIn2X1S)

---

Second option using `$reduce`,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `items` array, check condition if status match then sum with value

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      itemOn: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$items",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.status", "On"] },
              { $sum: ["$$value", 1] },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7JCmAPalQRY)

Comment: Love this approach, is working perfectly, thanks for you answer! 

But i am still checking my code and i really dont understand why it is not working :/ what am i doing wrong?

Comment: items is an array and for sum it requires to iterate through element by element, using such operators like, $map, $reduce, $filter etc.. you can look at second approach like your